# ISODate format in mongodb version

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, isodate

I had restored MongoDB server version: 4.2.3 to MongoDB server version: 4.2.7 and I had an error about `ISODate` as below when saving data to the database again:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed4b193ed6fab6d2272c5c4"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T05:59:59Z") } #new data run after change db (it must disappear for unique)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed33bef1e499012bf35e412"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T04:59:59.999Z") } #old data
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed4b193ed6fab6d2272c5c3"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T04:59:59Z") } #new data run after change db (it must disappear for unique)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed32de165269b416f6c7362"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T03:59:59.999Z") } #old data
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed4b193ed6fab6d2272c5c2"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T03:59:59Z") } #new data run after change db (it must disappear for unique)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed31fcff2a5076cc947bc02"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T02:59:59.999Z") } #old data
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed311bfb0d88300f81e90d2"), "id" : 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-05-31T01:59:59.999Z") } #old data
```

I have an index `id` and `timestamp` which is unique, but because timestamp has microseconds, not exactly so. Please give me a solution to keep microseconds in an `ISODate`.

PS: my code did not change. I use PHP and always format dates with `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB time resolution is 1 millisecond. Values with more precision will be truncated to millisecond precision.